# Using JsonReader to read json url

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to read json url using JsonReader!. Once I call `reader.beginArray()`, I get:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING.

This is the json url :

http://www.metlink.org.nz/stop/nearbystopdata?lat=-41.278407655948&lng=174.77938892631

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result = "";
        String url="http://www.metlink.org.nz/stop/nearbystopdata?lat=-41.278407655948&lng=174.77938892631";

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        try {

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            InputStream  in=response.getEntity().getContent();

            JsonReader reader ;

            reader= new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
            reader.setLenient(true);


             try {
                 listData=(ArrayList<DivanData>) readMessagesArray(reader);
             }
             finally {
               reader.close();
             }





        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }


      public ArrayList<DivanData> readMessagesArray(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
             ArrayList<DivanData> messages = new ArrayList();

             try {
                 reader.beginArray();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             while (reader.hasNext()) {
               messages.add(readMessage(reader));
             }
             reader.endArray();
             return messages;
           }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://www.metlink.org.nz/stop/nearbystopdata ? lat=-41.278407655948&lng=174.77938892631

Comment: I just checked your endpoint and the response **is not a JSON**, it's a html page with the json in its body. That's why you get that you are passing a String to your jsonReader.

Comment: Your url is a web page is not a JSON, try using a rest client for your navigator, that is the best way to you for check your web service.

Comment: is there any way to get JsonReader from this json string

Answer (score 0):

Since you have html with content why not try to fetch json as a string from the html using jsoup (http://jsoup.org/). It's really simple and requires less code:

```
    Document d;
    String url="your_url";
    d = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Element p = d.select("body p").first(); // fetch from p tag content
    String jsonString = p.text();
```